# terraform put module version to tags

Tags: terraform

I need a help with terraform, in a lot of plaices we use next code:

```
 module "supermodule-vpc" {
    source              = "git::ssh://git@github.company/oursupermodule.git?ref=v0.6.16"
}
```

Probably someone of you have an idea how it possible to put module version to tags, as example, I want to set new tag with module version which used to provision environment.

Tag can look likes:

```
  ProvisionedVersion = v0.6.16
```

Comment: hi, sorry but neither a try what you already testet nor told you how you wsnt to solve it, powershdll, bash? Your question is such what Kind of low Quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can't infer it, the only way is to duplicate the version as an additional variable. The obvious way would be to try and do something like this:

```
locals {
  version = "v0.6.16"
}

module "supermodule-vpc" {
  source  = "git::ssh://git@github.company/oursupermodule.git?ref=${local.version}"
  version = "${local.version}"
}
```

However this will produce an error as the module source cannot contain variables, so you're going to end up with something like this:

```
module "supermodule-vpc" {
  source  = "git::ssh://git@github.company/oursupermodule.git?ref=v0.6.16"
  version = "v0.6.16"
}
```

And when you bump one version string, remember to bump the other one.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response.
Probably it will be the best to raise question to terraform support guys, I think somebody should be intersted in this functionality